# The flag value "before insert, after insert" is not in the correct format for "array."

Tags: salesforcedx

If I execute the following;

```
sfdx force:apex:trigger:create --help
```

Then I get output that includes;

```
EXAMPLES
  $ sfdx force:apex:trigger:create -n MyTrigger
  $ sfdx force:apex:trigger:create -n MyTrigger -s Account -e 'before insert, after insert'
  $ sfdx force:apex:trigger:create -n MyTrigger -d triggers
```

But if I run the second example, I get this;

```
ERROR running force:apex:trigger:create:  The flag value "'before" is not in the correct format for
"array." Must only contain values in [before insert,before update,before delete,after insert,after
update,after delete,after undelete].
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The space after the comma is errant. The following works:

```
$ sfdx force:apex:trigger:create -n MyTrigger -s Account -e 'before insert,after insert'
```

I'll let someone know about this. I think it's a bug, as other commands, such as force:source:retrieve, allow spaces in their parameters.

Comment: I get the same error after removing the space; sfdx-cli/7.52.0-c5ad5c3eff win32-x64 node-v10.15.3

Comment: Strange, working for me too without the space.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams Actually, what terminal are you using? You may need to use `"` instead of `'` in some terminals to quote the string, or you can use the alternative of escaping the spaces: `-e before\ insert,after\ insert`.